# Gradle Sync Failed but Project is running without error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I know it is very strange. I've started Android studio today and "Gradle Sync Failed" message started to being shown with no error. Everything was working fine till I last closed the Android Studio yesterday. Then I tried to run the project, it runs successfully but still, the Gradle sync error is showing and XML layout preview is not displaying due to gradle sync error. I tried the following things to get rid of it:

1. run the command `gradlew clean build --stacktrace`
2. `gradlew clearBuildCache`
3. Invalidate/Restart Android Studio
4. Delete `.gradle` folder in C:\Users
5. Deleted the `app/build` folders manually

Following are the gradle log.

```
INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started setup of project 'projectName'. 
INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SETUP_STARTED 
INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed (29 s 70 ms) 
INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: SYNC_FINISHED 
INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Finishing batch update for project: Project
```

**PS:** It's nothing wrong with Android Studio because it's working fine with Another project.

**Edit**

Here is my **app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'xxxx'
            keyPassword 'xxxxx'
            storeFile file('../keystore/xxxx-xxxx.jks')
            storePassword 'xxxxxx'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }

    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {

        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
            minifyEnabled false

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles /*getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),*/ 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    //Other
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.crealsolutions.real-lib:real-lib:1.0.4'

    //View
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'

    // Retrofit2
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'

    //Fingerprint
    implementation 'me.aflak.libraries:fingerprint:2.5.3'

    //OTP View
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and here is the **project/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'

    repositories {

        google()

        jcenter()

        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: how are your `build.gradle` and `app/build.gradle` like?

Comment: @shizhen I've added the build.gradle of app and project

Comment: there are two `build.gradle`, the top level one is for your gradle plugin version and class path configurations, can you also post that one?

Comment: @shizhen sorry, I've posted it now

Comment: It looks normal for both gradle files, what is the detailed logs of this command `gradlew clean build --stacktrace --debug` ? Probably adding `--debug` can get more useful logs.

Comment: It's showing gradle build successfully

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182987/discussion-between-shizhen-and-waqar-khan).

Answer (score 1):

After the struggle of 8 Hours, I've fixed the issue by removing this from the manifest, which was required by a library

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        tools:overrideLibrary="me.aflak.libraries" />
```

required by:

```
implementation 'me.aflak.libraries:fingerprint:2.5.3'
```